# finding values for a parameters to make the limit finite

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

So I just got this question on my test today:

> Find the values of the parameter $a$ for which:
>   $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left ( n^{a}\times \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n^2+1}-n} \right ) $$ is finite

I figured out that when $a=-0.5$ the limit is $1$ but I'm pretty sure I missed some values, so how should I go about solving a question like this?

Answer (score 1):

Thinking to the [conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_(square_roots)) you get

$$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n^2+1}-n} = \frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n} \simeq \sqrt n $$ as $n \to \infty$?

Therefore

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left ( n^{a}* \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n^2+1}-n} \right )$$ is finite if and only if $a \le -1/2$.

Comment: using the conjugate I got exactly that then i factored out n from the top and the $\sqrt{n}$ from the bottom which left me with square root of infinty in the numerator so how can a be anything other the -0.5 because the I will get 2 over infinity

Comment: @ORRAVRAHAM No, the lower $a$ is, the quicker $n^a \sqrt n$ will go $0$ at $\infty$. For example with $a = -1$ you get $\frac{\sqrt n}{n}$.

Comment: There's an error in the numerator (conjugate of denominator).

Comment: @Bernard I don't understand your comment???

Comment: The conjugate of the denominator is $\sqrt{n^2+1}+n$

Comment: @Bernard Thanks. I see now reading with more care!

Answer (score 0):

Through algebraic manipulation, you can see that the limit you want to compute is 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{a+\frac 12},
$$
which will converge if and only if $a \leq -\frac 12$. The limit will be 1 when $a=-\frac 12$ and zero when $a < -\frac 12$.

Answer (score 0):

To make it rigourous and short, use *asymptotic equivalence*:

As already mentioned, using conjugates, you obtain
$$ \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n^2+1}-n} = \frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n} \sim_\infty \frac{2n}{2\sqrt n}=\sqrt n$$
so that
$$ n^a\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n^2+1}-n}\sim_\infty n^a\sqrt n= n^{a+\tfrac12},$$
whih has a finite limit if and only $a<-\frac12\;$ (limit $0$) or $a=-\frac12\;$ (lim $1$).